# Django serve static files directory like small html app

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I have a webpage in django 1.6 and now i got an online catalogue in html, swf, js. It is working OK when i open it's directory directly (http://myotherapp.com/mydirectory)it calls index.html inside and everything works fine, because it has relative urls, but when i host it in django with different url for example http://myapp.com/publication/1 it won't get any of css and js attached relatively. I know i can change files path in index.html but there will be more packages like this one and end-user of website can't handle this.

I am managing zipped catalogues via django admin app.

Now i have a workaround. I upload zipped package, unzip it to my media/static directory and I use regexp to modify uploaded and unzipped index.html js/css/swf relative paths to absolute but if company who does this online catalogue will change structure or add new files it won't be working because i search relative urls like this by name: "book.swf" or "js/books.swf" and then I change it to absolute. Problem is I can not make it more flexible because there is many of JS code (names of these css/js/swf files are used in JS also) in html.

Example url now: http://myapp.com/publication/1, it uses uploaded index.html from my media directory as template .

This solution it's not perfect because for example it can't be relocated with js to mobile/index.html and show mobile version of catalogue.

But how to do it in django/python way for production?

Comment: Ok to clarify: I want to keep my unzipped archive in media foler, for example /media/publication/2, there is index.html inside this directory. And now I want to call it like this: myapp.com/media/publications/2 beacuse of assets files linked with relative links like src="js/book.js"

Answer (score 1):

You have to serve static files from your HTTP server, configure it to do so relating to the STATIC_URL setting from settings.py file.

Ensure you've placed those static files inside local static app's directory.

Then run ./manage.py collectstatic to retrieve those files to the STATIC_ROOT directory, where they'll be served from.

Inside your templates, you should use static files as following :

```
{% load static %}
<img src='{% static "my_app/myexample.jpg" %}' alt='someimg'>
```

Automatically refering to your settings configuration regarding statics file.

Source: 
[Django Static files documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/)

Comment: Yeah but there is one problem. End-user can't edit index.html. There would be one more person needed to edit this file and add static. What more static files are different for every zipped catalogue

Comment: As mdgargacz asked: can you clarify the workflow of the issue, what would you like to achieve ?

Comment: Ok to clarify: I want to keep my unzipped archive in media foler, for example /media/publication/2, there is index.html inside this directory. And now I want to call it like this: myapp.com/media/publications/2 beacuse of assets files linked with relative links like src="js/book.js"

Comment: So each "user" have his own index with relative static files right ?

Comment: Each publication has index and it's files are in this directory named it's id :) Users are not releated with this app

Comment: Why aren't you templating an only index.html with with different static files stored in a directory named after the id of the publication ?

Comment: Because index.html can be different for each publication. I want to achieve something that i could do in PHP's codeigniter or kohana. I could create a directory in catalogue where my domain linked and then i could do http://mydomain.example.com/mydirectory and index.html in mydirectory was shown

Answer (score 1):

When you to render templates in django, you also should set properly static settings :

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

in urls:

```
    urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
    ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

in template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "my_app/myexample.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
```

Here's a django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/), clarifying this attempt

### EDIT/ Solution using django models

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
class Publication(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    # other fields

class MyFilesModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='some/place/in/media')
    publication = models.ForeignKey('Publication', related_name='files')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('')
    # other fields
```

admin.py (to easily add publications and files):

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Publication)
admin.site.register(MyFilesModel)
```

views.py:

```
def show_publication_list(request, publication_id):
    publication = get_object_or_404(Publication, pk=publication_id)
    context = dict(publication=publication)
    return render(request, 'template/path', context, content_type='application/xhtml+xml')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url('^publication/(?P<publication_id>\d+)/?$',
                           show_publication_list))
```

template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>{{ publication.name }}</h1>
<h3>Files:</h3>
<ul>
    {% for file in publication.files %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ file.url }}" target="_blank">{{ file.name }}</a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}

</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

In this solution you will be able to add publications and assign files to them from django admin level. No need to upload them manually.

Comment: Yeah but there is one problem. End-user can't edit index.html. There would be one more person needed to edit this file and add static. What more static files are different for every zipped catalogue

Comment: can you clarify the workflow of the issue, what would you like to achieve ?

Comment: Ok to clarify: I want to keep my unzipped archive in media foler, for example /media/publication/2, there is index.html inside this directory. And now I want to call it like this: myapp.com/media/publications/2 beacuse of assets files linked with relative links like src="js/book.js"

Comment: In django I would create a model for publication, and File model with foreign key to publication. Then create a view responsible for listing files for user. You would be able to add those files by django admin. I can prepare this structure for you if you're interested in this solution.

Comment: Yeah but there is still problem with relative urls in index.html and i want files  connected to one publication, not to user :)

Comment: by 'responsible for listing files for user' I didn't mean relation to user model. When you make this 'django way' using models, there won't be no problem with paths.  You would have one django view which will take publication_id argument and it would list all files related to publication. I will write another answer soon so you will be able to test this attempt.

Comment: I think we misunderstood each other. I have a zip package. In there i have index.html, some js, some css and some swf. When i run index.html from my desktop in browser it is good because it has relative paths in it. So when I have \projects\test\ in my browser it users index.html and relative paths are OK because js directory is inside test directory. But in django i have problem because when url changes to /publication/2, relative urls are not working anymore. Of course I can edit it by myself, but end user of app can't do that. In your solution there is files listing, not showing index.html

Comment: To clarify: my publication has in main catalogue: index.html, 2 swf files, mobile catalogue with mobile version of app, js directory, files directory. It is +- 2000 files. And im my index.html I have some files included, for example:`<link rel="image_src" href="files/shot.png"/>`, `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>`, some js: `window.location = "mobile/index.html"+(window.location.hash?window.location.hash:'');`, `swfobject.embedSWF(
                "book.swf")`.

Comment: And i am trying to keep this accessible in my webpage without rewriting all of these relative urls every time i upload something new. So as I asked on the begining in PHP kohana i could create direcotry in main folder and access it without any troubles, is any way to do that in django? For example in static or media directory?